# mod_rewrite, Centos and WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently installed wordpress with my old backup and from another host on my VPS, centos 6 64 bits

The problem is permalinks, mod_rewrite is enabled, and this is the only website on my VPS, which is on dir /home/wasdlife.com/www

My HTTPD.conf

```
<Directory /home/wasdlife.com/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And also, i am using apache.

.htaccess is automaticly made, and this is his source

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and its chmoded. So, the main problem is that i can see posts, pages if i set permalinks on default, but if i set on custom, it will show page not found.

Error log says that there is no file or directory /categories.

I am using webmin, and i think it is something with permission.

Comment: Make sure you have a mod_rewrite enabled. Run `httpd -M` and check.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6ydj9tUz it is

Comment: Did you restart apache after editing the httpd.conf file?